# How to attain this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find the second last digit of a given input(negative input). If the input is a single digit number(example -9) the program should return -1.(I don't want to use else for the latter condition, I want it's logic.)
My program :

```
a=int(input(" enter no. " ))
if a<0:
   a=a*-1
   a%=100
   a/=10
   print(int(a))
if a<0 and a%10==a :
    print("-1")
```

But my code is giving 0 for any negative single digit input. How to alter it? I know I can use else to print -1 but I don't want to do that, I just need the logic for negative single digit input. I am a beginner please help.
Thanks much:)

Comment: The second `if` statement will always fail because by the time you get to it you've already inverted the sign, but the first `if` seems to work. Tested with `-1234`, prints `3`. What's wrong with using `else`, anyway?

Comment: Why are you doing `a/=10`?  For a "single digit" input (like 9), you'd get `0.9`.  Then when you do `int(a)`, you are _truncating_ that to `0`.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with using else, I just want to know how to use an if statement for a negative single digit number. Is there a logic for that @TigerhawkT3

Comment: I used a/10 because I wanted to print only the second last digit @RocketHazmat

Comment: Well, `a%10==a` isn't the right way to check for a single-digit negative number. Did you try that code on some sample inputs and see what it produces?

Comment: I recommend using a post title with a bit more meaning. The current one could be anything. Spaces around operators are also nice. Beyond that, I'm not really sure what your spec is for this program. Can you edit the post to clarify? Thanks.

Comment: Since you just want to change 0 to -1 anyway, you could just make your first `if` statement end with `print(int(a) or -1)`, though.

Comment: Yeah (a%10==a)  works only for positive single digit input, I didn't know how to do for negative single digit input @TigerhawkT3

Comment: Invert the sign first, maybe? Or compare it to `a+10`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this all fairly easily by treating the integer as a string.

```
if a < 0:
  a *= -1
b = str(a)
if len(b) == 1:
  a = -1
if len(b) > 1:
  a = int(b[-2])
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can do is to multiplie by -1 if its negative that's already good , secondly you will do `a = a / 10` , then if your number is less than 0 its a single digit

```
a=int(input(" enter no. " ))
if (a<0 ) :
   a = a * -1
a = a / 10
if (a<0) :
   # its a single digit
```